# Determining the order and degree of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Problem:** Determine the order and degree of $(\frac{dr}{d\theta})^{4/3} + r = 2\theta$.

**Attempt:** From what I know, order means the highest derivative of the equation while degree is the exponent of that order. So in the equation, $\frac{dr}{d\theta}$ is the highest and is in first derivative, in which its exponent is $\frac{4}{3}$. So answer should be "Order : $1$ ; Degree : $\frac{4}{3}$".

**Inquiry:** However, the answer key on the book shows that the degree is actualy $4$. So I want to ask whether if I'm wrong or the book is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: As the equation is not a polynomial, any answer regarding the degree is ambiguous. Was there any more specific definition given that applies to non-integer powers?

Comment: See that as $3$ is odd the DE is equivalent to $(\frac{dr}{d\theta})^4 = (2\theta-r)^3$

Comment: @Cesareo Ohh. So in problems like this, I need to arrange it first in a decreasing exponent order polynomial, or convert it to its simplified form. Haven't encountered a problem like this before, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is cause if you want to identify the order of the ODE like in polynomials you need to have "something" elevated to an integer $n\ge 0$ so

$$\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^{4/3}+r=2\theta\rightarrow \left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^{4/3}=2\theta-r$$

$$\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^4=(2\theta-r)^3$$
Then $n=4$; therefore is a First Order ODE of $4^{th}$ degree.